# PHP fifo queue system over multiple server

Tags: php, queue

I'm trying to build a queue system with a [FIFO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.posix-mkfifo.php) file. This is actually working prety fine on my local development machine. But when I want to deploy to production, I'm running into the issue that my WEB server and CLI server are two seperate servers. And so the fifo file is not working when the listener is started on the CLI server and something is added from the WEB server.

So I need to start the listener from the WEB SAPI, but how can I do that? And also, if it crashes, it needs to be restarted again.

I know how to do this all from just on server, but no idea how to do so on multiple server setup.

The code:

```
<?php
//queue-listener.php

function process($job) {
    sleep(1); //. make it look like we did work.
    return;
}

$queue = array();

//////// setup our named pipe ////////
$pipefile = '/storage/queueserver';

umask(0);
if(!file_exists($pipefile)){
    if(!posix_mkfifo($pipefile,0666)) {
        die('unable to create named pipe');
    }
}

$pipe = fopen($pipefile,'r+');
if(!$pipe) die('unable to open the named pipe');
stream_set_blocking($pipe,false);

//////// process the queue ////////
while(1) {

    while($input = trim(fgets($pipe))) {
        stream_set_blocking($pipe,false);
        $queue[] = $input;
    }

    $job = current($queue);
    $jobkey = key($queue);
    if($job) {
        echo 'processing job ', $job, PHP_EOL;

        process($job);

        next($queue);
        unset($job,$queue[$jobkey]);
    } else {
        echo 'no jobs to do - waiting...', PHP_EOL;
        stream_set_blocking($pipe,true);
    }
}
```

Code for adding something to queue

```
$pipefile = '/storage/queueserver';
$fhp = fopen($pipefile, 'r+') or die ("can't open file $pipefile");
fwrite($fhp, "GenerateLabel|". date('H:i:s')."\n");
```

Comment: i guess we need code. As ever.

Comment: @delboy1978uk have you not spec'd into the telepath skill tree yet? :p

Comment: no, im stuck on a legacy setup :-P

Comment: @delboy1978uk, I thought the code was irrelevant for starting a process. My mistake, added it!

Comment: @delboy1978uk ah, did they finally re-release legacy?! I've been waiting for that for years, now I can go back and make the same mistakes :p

Comment: In short, you cannot, or more accurately, you should not.  Whatever you are using the FIFO for needs to be conceptually ported to some kind of RPC over IP.  This is not going to be a trivial answer and will require a substantial re-architecture of your current solution.  It sounds like you are going to be better off using an existing FIFO job queue to do what you are trying to bootstrap.

Comment: @AlexBarker, ok, do you have examples for it? I need to detach tasks so I can run code async.

Comment: Found something: https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev